# How can I tell when `hg push` failed (as opposed to "no changes")

Tags: bash, mercurial

According to `hg help push`, it

> Returns 0 if push was successful, 1 if nothing to push.

Now, I don't have a beard, but this does not seem like the "Unixy" way.

For example

```
set -e
hg push -R ~/some-repo
# never get here if push aborts for any reason
# ...OR if some-repo has no changes
exit 0
```

I can't imagine why I'd want `hg push` to behave this way, especially since the informational command `hg out` returns exactly the same status code.

So my question is, how can I tell when `hg push` actually failed?  Do I have to read the stream output?

(Incidentally, someone [pointed out](http://selenic.com/pipermail/mercurial-devel/2012-January/037720.html) in Janaruy 2012 that it wasn't working this way, and they fixed the program instead of the documentation.)

(Also I know that `set -e` [has issues](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).  This is not about that.)

Comment: -1 for not having a beard... but +2 for good question and good name. My instance seems to return 255 (at least for repo not found), but I'd like to see documentation for what is returned for which errors.

Comment: Have you tried checking the exit code `echo $?` just after the `hg push` command. Put a if condition to that. `if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then do this...`

Comment: @iamauser and @iamnotmaynard, I also get `255` for various error conditions, so I guess I can just do `set +e` and test for `1` or `0`.

Comment: @harpo In your question you mentioned, "never get here if it fails" that I suppose would result in non-zero exit code for the `hg push` command.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard and iamauser, thanks for your help.  I posted my solution for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @iamnotmaynard indicated in the comments, `hg push` exits with `255` for errors.  So you can do something like this

```
set +e
hg push -R $repo
status=$?
set -e
if [[ ! "01" =~ $status ]]; then
    exit 1
fi
```

It still makes no sense to me, but moving on.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's necessary to use `set +e` and `set -e`, but you could just have done `hg push -R "$repo"(newline)[[ $? == [01] ]] || exit 1`. And if you really have to use `set -e` for your other commands. Just use it after those two lines.

Comment: @konsolebox, if the script has done `set -e` already, then the `push` by itself will cause an abort when the exit status is 1.  However, I'm sure there's a more concise way to write it, along the lines of your suggestion.  Non-zero status will not cause abort, for instance, if the `push` is in a pipeline.

Comment: Well I did consider the possibility that `set -e` was set before it. If that was the case then you could still place `set +e` before `hg push`. Your example does not show `hg push` sending output through a pipeline or running through it but if you're concerned about it just enable `pipefail`. I'll post an example way to do it.

Comment: Two nicer ways to handle the status. Firstly, `status=0; some_command || status=$?` will leave you with the status in `status`, without tripping `-e`.  Secondly, `if some_command; then whenever; else wherever; fi` - using a command in a test does not trip `-e`, although it arguably hides the command a bit.

Answer (score 2):

First example:

```
read -a ERREXITSAVE < <(shopt -o -p errexit)
set +o errexit

hg push -R "$repo"
[[ $? == [01] ]] || exit 1

"${ERREXITSAVE[@]}"
```

Second example:

```
read -a ERREXITSAVE < <(shopt -o -p errexit)
read -a LASTPIPESAVE < <(shopt -o -p lastpipe)

set +o errexit
set -o lastpipe

... | ( hg push -R "$repo"; [[ $? == [01] ]]; ) | ... || exit 1

"${ERREXITSAVE[@]}"
"${LASTPIPESAVE[@]}"
```